# Android - GPS + Accelerometer - Distance between two moments

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, accelerometer

Are there some high level api like this on Android world?

```
DistanceCalculator dc = new DistanceCalculator();
dc.start();
//some walking, driving, whatever
float distanceInMeters = dc.stop();
```

> I'm looking for something that mix the things up (gps, accelerometer, etc) to fix errors and compensate bad accuracy, etc. For example, if i drive arround the square quickly starting and ending to same point, and there wasn't enough time to get new coodinates. Am i lost?

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to follow below steps,
1. Register location listener.
2. Cache the last known location (you need to put smart filter on accuracy level). 
3. Calculate the distance between simple Android API method [distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29)

or else you can write you own mechanism for distance calculation between to lat/long.

One thing is clear that, there is not direct API or method which you give you distance.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if i drive arround the square quickly starting and
>   ending to same point, and there wasn't enough time to get new
>   coordinates. Am i lost?

If you are moving, wou get every second a GPS fix, that is sufficient for distance measurement.